# Creating a branch from a remote branch (EGit)

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I am using EGit 2.1.0 in eclipse juno.

On a repository I right-click the **origin/master** branch in the **Remote Tracking** folder and create a new branch:

```
Source ref: refs/remotes/origin/master
Branch name: refs/heads/MyFeature
Merge=true
Checkout=true
```

So the **MyFeature** branch is *based* on the content of **origin/master** at the time its created. As a result a local branch **MyFeature** is created in the **Local** folder.

If I configure the branch is says:

```
Upstream Branch: refs/heads/master
Remote: origin
```

I am confused about this last part. The **MyFeature** branch is based on **origin/master**. Why does it default to pull changes from the local master branch and not the remote master branch (which it was based on)?

From command-line you would do:

```
$ git branch --track MyFeature origin/master
Branch MyFeature set up to track remote branch refs/remotes/origin/master.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Upstream branch' means the branch in the upstream repository. "`refs/heads/master` in `origin`" is another (longer but more precise) way of saying "`origin/master`".

Comment: Ok so its the branch seem from whatever is chosen in the "Remote" view. I guess the equivalent would be : "Upstream branch=refs/remotes/origin/master", remote="."

Comment: almost, except that git knows where to push and to fetch from origin before doing a merge when your run `git pull`

Comment: Sort of, and you may want to check out GitGuys' [article](http://www.gitguys.com/topics/tracking-branches-and-remote-tracking-branches/) on the topic. `refs/remotes/origin/master` is your local copy of the `refs/heads/master` branch on the `origin` remote. Your local `refs/heads/MyFeature` branch is tracking `refs/heads/master` on `origin` using its local copy (the remote tracker), `refs/remotes/origin/master`.

Answer (score 1):

If you check your .git/config file or run git config -l, then you'll see the following:

```
branch.MyFeature.remote=origin
branch.MyFeature.merge=refs/heads/master
```

This means that your MyFeature branch tracks the refs/heads/master ref (master branch for short) of your origin remote. In this case the refs/heads/master does not mean your local refs/heads/master but it's from your remote's point of view. So when you fetch/pull from the remote it sends a message like this: "Dear Origin! Please send me your refs/heads/master. Thanks." :)